# 'xlongrightarrow' is not working

Tags: arrows

I know about  `\xrightarrow (text)`.
e.g.,

```
\documentclass{book}
\begin{document}
$A \xrightarrow{f} B$  
\end{document}
```

Gives:
[image]
 But  if I try to do `$A \xlongrightarrow{f} B $`    to have

[image]

I get an error. I don't know how to fix this problem.

Comment: `\xlongrightarrow` is provided in [extarrows](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/extarrows) package, add `\usepackage{extarrows}` in preamble.

Comment: I have used this package but it shows the error : "'extraarrow.sty' not found.^^M"

Comment: A simple approach is to download [extraarrow.sty](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/extarrows/extarrows.sty) and place in your working folder. If you are using TeXLive 2012, it should be there, otherwise update TeX distro in 15 days with [TeXLive 2013](http://tug.org/texlive/acquire.html). Note: Type at Terminal window `kpsewhich  extarrows.sty` to verify if a `.sty` exists or not.

Comment: BTW Notice its `extarrows.sty` instead of `extraarrow.sty` you might have a typo error.Even i have typed wrong in above comment sorry :).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

But `\xrightarrow` does the work, e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

%$A \xlongrightarrow{f} B $ 
$A \xrightarrow{\qquad f\qquad} B $ 

\end{document}
```

[image]